# How to install Python from .tar files on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, installation

How do I install Python versions without an installer, and only a .tar/.tar.gz/.tar.xz on Windows?

I extracted it to a folder and tried `python setup.py install`, because, apparently, that's how you do it. I got this response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(user)\Documents\Downloads\Python-3.7.10\setup.py", line 29, in <module>
    set_compiler_flags('CFLAGS', 'PY_CFLAGS_NODIST')
  File "C:\Users\(user)\Documents\Downloads\Python-3.7.10\setup.py", line 27, in set_compiler_flags
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()[compiler_flags] = flags + ' ' + py_flags_nodist
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I tried messing around with pcbuild and reading countless READMEs and still have no idea what to do. I have [Visual Studio 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2019) installed, which may or may not be important. I am currently running Python 3.9.2 and have 3.8.8 installed using the regular .exe installer. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/PCbuild/readme.txt

Comment: @Axe319 yes, but I didn't get what to do. Build.bat keeps installing python 3.9.2 in not even the right directory

Comment: The last 3.9 version with a windows installer is 3.9.13.  I haven't found any way of installing the releases with .tgz files.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You really don't want to build Python from source if you have never done anything like this before.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot or directory listing of what's inside of the parent directory after decompressing?   You have to build the file from source and I'm curious what's inside of the source package you downloaded.

Answer (score -2):

The error you are seeing is because `py_flags_nodist` is not defined. It looks like the code is trying to concatenate a string with a NoneType object. You may need to check your setup.py file to see why it's trying to do this.

Comment: This is both wrong (it has nothing to do with `py_flags_nodist`), and completely misses the point of the question

Comment: Your answer demonstrates that you have not properly understood the nature of the problem and you have missed the point.